# Maven3 multiple repos

Tags: maven-3

I'm new to Maven.
I have a POM that does not specify a repo, and I want to download Spring's mobile stuff, and the maven directions specify a repo:

```
<repository>
<id>springsource-repo</id>
<name>SpringSource Repository</name>
<url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
```

and

```
<repository>
<id>springsource-milestone</id>
<name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
<url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
```

How do I edit my POM to use these repos for the Spring mobile dependencies, but keep on using the master repo for the other dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try out adding repositories tag as mentioned in maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html